# What is the output type of cts.uris in MarkLogic?

Tags: javascript, object, types, marklogic

I'm using cts.uris in my search query. I'm assigning it to a variable like:

```
var x = cts.uris(...);
```

What is the output type of x?

I'm using JSON documents in my application and want to use xdmp.nodeReplace on some 2 objects. I'm performing an update on my document after checking the value of "x" to be valid or not after writing a search query inside cts.uris.

```
if(x.toString().length>0)

//x is cts.uris output. Checking if it gets a value then do the update like this.

{

var newObject = x; 

newObject.field1="new value";
//field 1 value updated in the clone of original file

newObject.field2="new value"; //same as above

 return xdmp.nodeReplace(x, newobj);

}
```

I expect the newObject to have all the contents of the origial file that we fetch and put in "x" and then update the values as given in the above code.
Once it is updated then it should replace the original document with the new values.
I'm currently getting an error like: "XDMP-ARGTYPE: xdmp.nodeReplace"

Answer (score 0):

[cts.uris](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.uris) returns a [Sequence](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref/api#id_59096) of uris. You probably want to iterate over the Sequence using a JavaScript `for..of` construct. An example is given in above link.

Note though that a uri is not a full document, but just its identifier. It doesn't make sense to assign values to it like that.

To make updates to documents inside MarkLogic, either reinsert the document, or read it using [cts.doc](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.doc), isolate the property you want to update, and nodeReplace it as you intended.

HTH!